Is it possible to shutdown SCR when high current is passing through it?
I have a project in which I need a controllable high voltage (400+ V) high current (10+ kA) pulse (from μs to ms.)
Obviously FETs won't cut it because the high voltage will destroy the channel of any FET with such high current rating.
IGBTs are the obvious choice but they are prohibitively expensive.
SCRs are cheap and can take a lot of punishment, but once triggered it won't open until the channel current drops.
Question:
Is there any alternative or methods to shutdown an SCR while a large current it passing through its channel?

For a speciality see GTO.

Why will HV burn the channel of a MOSFET?

@Andyaka because high-current (compared with SCR and IGBT) FET has rather low channel breakdown voltage.

@7E10FC9A You can get Silicon Carbide FETs that are rated for such voltages. 400V is on the lower side of what FETs can do. Silicon carbide FETs are commonly found at up to 1200V ratings. GaN might be able to do 650 depending on where you get it. At thousands of amps however, it is nonsensical to use FETs as the heating will be astronomical and uneven.

At 1mOhm (by paralleling like 6 of these: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/infineon-technologies/IMW65R007M2HXKSA1/22157513) 10kA makes 100kW of instantaneous heating (over a fraction of a second). With a 3.5V diode drop from an IGBT or GTO, it makes 35kW of heat. What you have on your hands is an expensive problem.

@theph The pulse is rather short, even with 100kW heating, at 100us it only generate 10J of heat. The pulse only fires every few seconds, so the heat dissipation is only few Watt at most. What I need is a switch that can handle the surge. Looks GTO or IGBT is the way to go.

You can use an external circuit to force commutate the current to zero, turning your SCR off. Given the cost of it, you'll be better off with an IGBT or possibly GTO.

Source: https://circuitdigest.com/tutorial/thyristor-commutation-technique
